# How to not hardcoding image extensions in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

How to not hardcoding image extensions in Java?

```
            switch(extension) {
                case "zip" -> {
                    FileUtil.saveFile(multipartFile, historyFolder, FileType.ZIP, backupFilePath);
                    FileUtil.saveFile(multipartFile, target, FileType.ZIP, filePath);
                }
                case "jpg", "jpeg", "png", ".bmp", ".svg", "webp", "jfif", "pjpeg", "pjp", "apng", "avif" -> {
                    FileUtil.saveFile(multipartFile, historyFolder, FileType.IMAGE, backupFilePath);
                    FileUtil.saveFile(multipartFile, target, FileType.IMAGE, filePath);
                }
                default -> throw new GlobalCustomException(ErrorCode.ILLIGAL_FILE_TYPE);
            }
```

Above is my code.

In the case statement, I have listed strings as hard-coded as jpg, jpeg....

This code is not flexible, so I'm sure there must be a better way.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me a solution that I'm not aware of.

Comment: We need more info like; FileUtil what is the package? What is multipartFile, byte[] or something else? Why do you save with FileType? You should normally save anything with any extension without providing de FileType.

Comment: If you want extensibility, maybe you should read about Service Provider Interface(SPI) and implement interfaces for different file types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of possible ways, you can use `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName()` like this.

```
String mimeType = java.net.URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName("test." + extension);
boolean isImage = mimeType != null && mimeType.startWith("image/")
```

You can add custom extensions to the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/content-types.properties` file.

Also see these questions.

- [How to get a file's Media Type (MIME type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/how-to-get-a-files-media-type-mime-type)
- [How to reliably detect file types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738597/how-to-reliably-detect-file-types)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using an array with extensions and pass in a case statement.
Take all the image formats as a single array element and zip format as another array element.

This should give the nearest logic.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700392/20191548

Try if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
String extension = "";

int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i > 0) {
    extension = fileName.substring(i+1);
}
extension=fileName.substring(0,i)+"."+extension;
FileUtil.saveFile(multipartFile, historyFolder, extension, backupFilePath); 
FileUtil.saveFile(multipartFile, target, extension, filePath);
```